# using @FILE in forfiles not working

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to build a batch file that deletes all excel files older than 30 days. So far I have the command:

```
forfiles -p"N:\QC\ATR's" -s -m*.xls* -d-30 -c"CMD /C del /f /q @FILE"
```

The only problem seems to be the fact that @FILE has a space in the folder/file name so the del command cannot find the specified path. For example, looking at the echoes from the command it says

```
Could Not Find N:\QC\ATR's\'-5
```

When it should really be looking for the path

```
N:\QC\ATR's\-5 brightness study
```

See what I mean? Is there a way to tell the @FILE variable to be wrapped in quotes or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just added Hex coded qoutes around the file variable

```
forfiles -p"N:\QC\ATR's" -s -m*.xls* -d-30 -c"CMD /C del /f /q ^0x22@FILE^0x22"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could try the following:**

```
SET FILE = -5 brightness study

forfiles -p"N:\QC\ATR's" -s -m*.xls* -d-30 -c"CMD /C del /f /q %FILE%"
```

**Check these sites for some assistance:**

http://ss64.com/nt/path.html

http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/server-management/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-batch-file-